# HTML 5 performance on Firefox?

Tags: performance, html

I tried this sample here:

http://9elements.com/io/projects/html5/canvas/

After a few minutes, Firefox slows down so much I can't even popup any menu. When I closed the tab, Firefox comes back to normal again.

So is HTML 5 really a good choice now ?

Comment: you mean canvas element not html5

Comment: It runs perfectly smoothly on FF on my setup. Maybe you've not got much memory and FF is having to switch to virtual memory? If so, it doesn't matter what you're trying to do; your PCs performance will seriously degrade once it has to address virtual memory...

Comment: I didn't say It didn't run smoothly, It did run smoothly :) I did say it has dramatic drain on the browser because I'm an intensive computer geek who opens a lot of tabs at the same time. I have no problem doing so with some flash videos or animations but on this one it was obviously a pain for Firefox at least on Windows 7 (I have a recent notebook with plenty of RAM 4 GB).

Answer (score 1):

it ran very well for me - both firefox and chrome, saying that - chrome was smooother, although you'd expect it with the weight of FF on your system.

But you bring up a good point. I've heard some people say Flash is dead and HTML5 is the new Flash - and I'm not sure how they consider the new HTML5 as a comparison.
I've also heard this is due to flash being closed and proprietary. But how does this differ than HTML5 in act?

Perhaps a little off topic but it is relative to the point, HTML5 is a wonderful magic and with it allows a greatly wanted upgrade to the now flagging HTML markup. It'll take some time before browsers catch up but thats only an issue now.

When was the last time HMTL got an upgrade? 97? 1998? so roughly 10 years since HTML caught up, so Browsers have 10 years toget to grips with HTML5

---

So ya. HTML5 is wonderful and I love and its good to get to know it, cus in 2 years - it'll be the standard.

Comment: Well after this experience I would prefer to wait 2 years then because implementing this on millions of my client's clients would be a huge professional risk for me :)

Hope it would take less than 2 years though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now is the time for HTML5. Browser support is good and growing very quickly. The power of the average computer is such that creating web applications that implement the more resource intensive HTML5 features is perfectly reasonable.

Also, as a point of correctness, you can't use the smoothness of one company's HTML5 experiment as a way of validating whether HTML5 is ready for wider use. I could create a C program that would repeatedly print out "Hello World", and do it so badly that after 5 mins your entire system grinds to a halt. Does that mean C isn't ready yet?

You also have to remember that when new technologies first come in, there are no widely established "best practices" or cunning tricks to squeeze every last bit of performance out of the new features. Even if computers / browser weren't ready for HTML5 yet (which I think they are), it needs to be released, adopted, and it's use refined so that those best practice patterns can emerge.

Answer (score 1):

What's your environment?  I tried that page with Firefox 3.6.3 on a PowerBook G4/1.67GHz, 2G RAM (a nice laptop when I bought it six years ago, but hardly a powerhouse by today's standards) and it ran fine for several minutes with no performance issues whatsoever.  It actually ran smoother than the typical youtube video does on this machine...