# Current state of Canvas performance(2012) -improving on Firefox?

Tags: performance, canvas

I've read these threads
[Poor performance of html5 canvas under firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342971/poor-performance-of-html5-canvas-under-firefox)
and
[HTML 5 performance on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839691/html-5-performance-on-firefox)

but they're over a year old.
I'm actively promoting use of the Canvas object in our studio, but need to suggest workarounds and performance tips for use in Firefox.

Can anyone offer their thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot has been happening/changing in one year regarding browser technologies. 
So I don't think that there are big performance issues regarding canvas and firefox.
There are several things to consider:
Recent browser versions support hardware accelerated 2D canvas. 
You might have to enable them manually (check about:flags).

You can test performance with these benchmarks:

- http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/asteroidsbench/
- http://c5bench.com/

Also check out the html5rocks article about canvas performance [pitfalls](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/).

Finally you can use some canvas libraries (i.e. [kineticjs](http://www.kineticjs.com/how-it-works.php)) that use multiple (hidden) layers to improve performance.

Comment: Interestingly c5bench crashes my chrome after a min or so!